# How can I add an icon for my third-party Odoo app

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I have developed an app that I want to publish in the Odoo App Store. The issue I am now facing is how to add an Icon for it that will be seen in the Apps tab once the app is installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have that icon file anywhere in the static directory of your app/module. Why static? Because it is easier to configure web caching (with apache or nginx) if every app/module has static files at the "same" directory.

You also have to tell your menu which icon file to use, like in the [Accounting App](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/167b1668450c5af44bc1d36d1c7d59921bc2b811/addons/account/views/account_menuitem.xml#L7).

```xml
<menuitem name="Invoicing"
        id="menu_finance"
        groups="account.group_account_readonly,account.group_account_invoice"
        web_icon="account,static/description/icon.png"
        sequence="55" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see in the [module](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/9c19460ce7fb1a16cfeed607e474e273f5ce690b/odoo/modules/module.py#L266) source code that Odoo will try to get the icon (`icon.png`) from the `static/description` directory:

```
def get_module_icon(module):
    iconpath = ['static', 'description', 'icon.png']
    if get_module_resource(module, *iconpath):
        return ('/' + module + '/') + '/'.join(iconpath)
    return '/base/'  + '/'.join(iconpath)
```

Or use the default icon located in `/base/static/description/icon.png`

To add an icon to your module just add a file named `icon.png` inside `/MODULE_DIRECTORY/static/description/`